# 'bin\setup' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to Ruby on Rails and I am trying to run some code that I downloaded from Github. There is written that first, we need to this command bin\setup, but if use back slash or slash it does not work and I get this error in command prompt 'bin\setup' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Does someone know what is missing? Thanks in advance.

Actually I get this for bin/setup in git bash:

```
bash: bin/setup: No such file or directory
```

And this

```
$ bin\setup
bash: binsetup: command not found
```

Comment: It seams like you don't have `.` in your PATH; just run `./bin/setup` from the correct location (which would be inside the Git folder that you downloaded)

Comment: @Fravadona With .  I still get: No such file or directory

Comment: Well, what can I say... `./bin/setup` is a relative PATH so you need to `cd` to the right place for it to work.

Comment: Hi, have you tried just `setup`? Sometimes, the `bin/` expression it's used to indicate that you should run the code inside a specific directory on the `$`, `bash`, or `Terminal` depending on your (OS) operative system.

Comment: @DangerR.Gálvez Yeah I tried and only setup, but still same...

Comment: Wich version of Rails are you using? You can run `rails about`, and paste here the outcome.

Comment: @DangerR.Gálvez This is version: Rails 6.1.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error: `bash: bin/setup: No such file or directory`, in this case, means that you're trying the setup the wrong file/folder.

In order to make it work, after you've cloned the project from Github, you'll need to access the correct application folder (e.g. `app_example_name`), and from there you should be able to do:

1. `bin/setup`
2. `rails server` or `rails s` (It's the same)
3. Visit http://localhost:3000/

Sometimes, you'll also need to install the ruby version of the cloned application first, and then you should be able to go.